# How to show all files of the project's folder in the left "files bar" in TeXnicCenter

Tags: texniccenter

I'm new to TeXnicCenter and would like to get it to act like Overleaf :
I have a project folder, with a tcp file and many tex and sty files, and more tex files in subfolder.

I would like the left side of the screen where I have a "files" sub-window showing my project folder in the file explorer way to display all of it content so I can easily navigate it.

However only the main file of my project show up in the folder, even thought there are many more in the actual folder on the disk.

Thank's a lot in advance for any help regarding this issue!

Comment: If you are new, do yourself a favour and look into more modern editors like texstudio instead of texniccenter

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz does it permit to have the project folder displayed in an overleaf manner? I'm doing a latex with many separate file so that's really the most important things for me :)

Comment: I believe it only lists the files that are currently open (being edited), which may or may not be part of the same project.  It would have to Build the project to locate all the \input, \include and \usepackage commands.  See also Build->Clean Project.